# Comment posted but still get "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When posting a comment on a post, the comment is correctly posted (can be seen in both side poster and postee).

but 
*FB Server* always returns

```
 {"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request  later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}
```

Testing with

```
 curl -i -x PROXY -d test=yes https://graph.facebook.com/POSTID/comments?access_token=VALIDUSERTOKEN&message=cool+but+prefer+200+as+response
```

?

Comment: same with official curl https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments

Comment: same issue. the post goes through but i get the same OAuthException error. I'm using the Facebook SDK php.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Facebook SDK php and was having the same issue. The message would post to a user's fan page but would throw the error you described.

I was able to resolve it by removing the "actions" from the message data variable. I'm not sure why but that stopped the error.